# Is there a way to pass an item to a dialog in another component in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dialog

I have a component with a `<v-data-table>` containing different items. In every row there is a button that opens a `<v-dialog>` that shows detailed information about the selected item. My problem is that I do not want one big component but different, smaller components.
So my question is how can I pass the item that I want to show in the dialog over to the dialog that's in another component?

Here is my Vue-code that opens the dialog.

```
<template v-slot:item.open="{ item }">
                <v-tooltip top>
                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                        <v-icon size="20px" color="green darken-1" v-on="on" @click="openDialog2(item)">
                            mdi-arrow-expand-all
                        </v-icon>
                    </template>
                    <span>Open</span>
                </v-tooltip>

<v-dialog
                v-if="this.dialog2"
                v-model="fullDialog"
                persistent
                max-width="1200"
        >
```

and the JavaScript code to hand over the item to the dialog (works if dialog and `<v-data-table>` are in the same component)

```
 openDialog2(item) {
                this.fullDialog = Object.assign({}, item);
                this.dialog2 = true;
            }
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you looked into Props? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Comment: Just to confirm by saying `item` you mean any `JS` property or value ?

Comment: @InchHigh that actually looks like what I am looking for, I'll review this later.

Comment: @SatyamPathak by item I mean the :items in <v-data-table>

Answer (score 0):

There can be a proper way I can prefer to do this.

**Vuex** State managment (https://vuex.vuejs.org/)

Whenever I think that a `data` can get shared to different components, I believe `state` management is the best way to do it.
**Why not prop and when  vuex** - well as you mentioned many different small `components` wish to read `data` or `manipulate` it so it will get little redundant that you pass `prop` in very deep level or different hierarchy. Read about how to include `vuex` in your project refere https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/.

State management is the single source of truth, when any component wants to access  any state can simply read it and the best part is if any component changes the state all other component using the same state has the reflection because it's binds to `vue` reactivity.

By saying `state` i refer to `item` you wish to pass to components